# SCAN traversal starting pos

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, disk

I've been reading up on SCAN and C-SCAN but can't find a definitive answer to my question.

If the head is starting positioned over track 10 and in your requests you have

5, 7 , 10, 13, 15

Will it access track 10, 5, 7 13... since it's already positioned over it, or will it's first be to go 5, 7, 10...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in such questions you are given the **initial direction** in which the *read/write* head of your disk is moving.

But in either case, since it is positioned on `track 10`, it will first serve that I/O request and then move on to server further I/O requests.

Lets just say the initial direction of the *read/write* head is towards greater number track.

Then, the order in which requests are served will be:

**SCAN**

```
10, 13, 15, 7, 5
```

**CSCAN**

```
10, 13, 15, 5, 7
```

Comment: Ah, so even though the head is positioned currently over 10, it will still serve 10 in the list?

Comment: @bhigg890 considering it has not yet served 10 in the list, then it will, otherwise it will move on.